# Xcode 11 blank white screen on device

Tags: xcode

I have a problem with debugging any app using Xcode 11.3.1.
The app builds very quickly (about 3 seconds), but after that, the device displays a white blank screen for a minute or two. On the Report navigator tab, it says that the app is running and debug is already in process but there are no logs. It happens with any app, even a newly created one.
Tried reproducing it on iPhone XS and iPhone 11 pro with 13.3.1 iOS version (the latest one at the moment) - the result is the same.
After this pause, I can debug the app as nothing happened. This behavior happens only during the debug session (no matter using cable or WiFi). If an app was already installed and launched directly from the phone - everything is fine.

Comment: @matt Thanks for a quick response. Actually, I tried it but the screen remained white. So it's not a splash screen.

Comment: Darn! Well, I’ve never experienced this issue so I’m a poor advisor. Can you download the 11.4 beta just to see if the issue persists?

Comment: @matt sure, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: I’m not promising anything! It’s just an experiment. :)

Comment: @matt, I've got some results. Loading still takes a minute, but with new Xcode I've started seeing splash screen instead of the white screen. Even though I tried clean/reinstall stuff previously, it still showed just a blank screen. So your first guess was the right one.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Jan the issue disappeared without any noticeable changes from my side, so not much helpful info at the end :(